# Windows Defender won't let an external drive (WD My Book) sleep

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, sleep, windows-defender

Well, the topic title says it all. I recently purchased a Western Digital My Book 8TB and no matter what I couldn't get it to stand by/sleep. I tried everything: messing around with USB power options, indexing, installing dedicated WD software that has a sleep timer - NOTHING worked. I tested the drive on MAC and it would go to sleep out of the box, without any additional drivers or software. So I made a clean Win10 install - no luck. Eventually I disabled Windows Defender Real Time Protection and grunt! - it goes to sleep after 10 minutes as it should.

Windows Defender real-time protection has to be turned off entirely; the moment I turn it ON, the disk wakes up. Excluding the disk as a folder doesn't work. Setting up registry values manually doesn't work. Modifying policies to disable USB drives scans also doesn't.

Is there any way to make Windows Defender stop bothering my disk?

Comment: Have you waited for Defender to check all files on the external HDD? Do a complete scan, if necessary? There is *no* reason Defender should keep activating the HDD.

Comment: Yet it does. The disk is empty. The moment I turn ON real-time protection the disk starts to spin and wakes up. It's a conundrum.

Comment: Look in diskmgt.msc to be sure there is only one partition. Also, is encryption in use?

Comment: There's only one partition. I don't know how to check the encryption thing.

Comment: Ok, I found something called "Bit-locker" (regarding the encryption) and it's turned off by default for my every drive. Also, I have an internal HDD that goes to sleep normally. So it looks like some annoying Defender bug. Sometimes it bothers the disk so much that my mouse starts to lag.

Comment: Do a complete virus scan; that is definitely *no* normal behavior for Defender with an external drive.

Comment: I did, even though it's a fresh install. It only found one SEVERE threat - my manual registry entries excluding the drive (that didn't work anyway), lol. Excluding doesn't work because it seems like it affects only scans while at fault here is the real time protection.

Answer (score 0):

I’m leaving this message for anyone with a similar problem who finds this topic.

Installing a different antivirus (ESET Internet Security in my case) resolved the issue. After 3 days of digging I found no solution to Win Defender bothering and waking up my external drive. Also, neither Defender nor ESET found any malware on my computer.